# Not running the apk file after signing (Problem in parsing the package after signing the apk.)

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, signature, sign

I got the apk output from the program using the following code

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi --obfuscate --split-debug-info=<directory>
```

Instead of , I wrote the storage path and got three output files, in addition to --obsfucate, the codes may have been obscured.
Now I created a keystore using the following code

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Instead of a nickname, I put the desired name of my key and entered the required information by pressing enter.

Now I put the app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk file next to this key and wrote the following code

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk alias_name
```

And instead of alias_name, I wrote the name of my key and after pressing enter, it showed the following text

> jar signed.
>
> Warning: The signer's certificate is self-signed. The SHA1 algorithm
> specified for the -digestalg option is considered a security risk and
> is disabled. The SHA1withRSA algorithm specified for the -sigalg
> option is considered a security risk and is disabled. POSIX file
> permission and/or symlink attributes detected. These attributes are
> ignored when signing and are not protected by the signature.

But now when I put the apk file in every phone, it says there is a problem in parsing the package.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I noted is, that you use *jarsigner*. The recommended way to sign your APK file via CLI is to use [apksigner](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner), which is part of the official Android SDK [Command Line Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/) (this link may solve other problems too) and, of course, of Android Studio's APK building toolchain. Take a look at the Android Dev Docs how to [sign your APK manually](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually).

The thing is, that *jarsigner* neither supports the newer [APK signing schemes](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/apksigning) nor does it have a clue about some specifics like that APKs which have need to run on API Level <= 17 must not use SHA-256. So, I assume that using *apksigner* with the proper options (esp. signing scheme) will solve the problem.